Is there a place where we can see the hats we have earned as a community?
Have you seen a snowflake icon in the top bar? This means that we are in Winterbash 2017, an event that will run from December 13th up to January 2nd this year. During this period of time, you can earn hats by completing certain tasks (something similar to a badge). Then your gravatar can "wear" these hats. It's a funny way to celebrate the many amazing people who make the community awesome. But, like past times, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.
In past years, we have asked the community if we wanted to participate in this event. This time we have not done it because Stack Exchange has decided that all sites would participate. Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat have an “I hate hats” option available.
As you can see at the Winterbash 2017 FAQ, if you want to see all hats you have earned, you can do it by looking at the hat rack on your user profile or by going to the site winterbash2017.stackexchange.com
and log in. But what about seeing all hats we have earned as a community: is there a site where we can see them all?

At the site winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/italian.stackexchange.com we can see all hats we have earned as a community. 
I hope you have lot of fun by participating at this event.
By the way, maybe you have notice that there is a hat called "And YOU Get A Hat!". You will earn it if our site collectively has at least 20 different hats, with the condition that you own any other hat. Will our community earn this hat? I hope so because that would mean a lot of participation these days doing good actions for our site ;).
Finally, today we have succeed in earning "And YOU Get A Hat!".
